# Expanding the quantum mechanical propagator in terms of the (non-degenerate) eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, propagator

Could anyone please help me with this derivation? I am struggling to see how the Propagator

[image]

Can be expanded out into the form

[image]

This is a non-degenerate two-level system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you dealing with a two-level system?

Comment: This is not generally true, so you need to say what the system *is*.

Comment: Yes sorry, two-level system! I imagine the completeness theorem and spectral decomposition will feature in here somewhere, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Hermitian matrix can be decomposed using the Pauli matrices as basis elements (including the identity matrix, noted as $\sigma_0$),
$$
H = \sum_{i=0}^3 a_i \sigma_i= a_0 +\vec{a}.\vec{\sigma},
$$
with $a_i$'s real numbers. The eigenvalues of $H$ are $\lambda_\pm = a_0\pm |\vec a|$.

Using the well-known formula for the [exponential of Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector), we obtain
$$
e^{-i H t}=e^{-i a_0 t}\left(\cos(|\vec a |t)-i (H-a_0)\frac{\sin(|\vec a |t)}{|\vec a|}\right),
$$
which leads to
$$
e^{-i H t}=e^{-i a_0 t}\left(\cos(|\vec a |t)+ia_0\frac{\sin(|\vec a |t)}{|\vec a|}\right)-i H e^{-i a_0 t}\frac{\sin(|\vec a |t)}{|\vec a|}.
$$

Using that $2|\vec a|=\lambda_+-\lambda_-$, we get the sought for equation
$$
e^{-i H t}=\frac{\lambda_+ e^{-i\lambda_-t}-\lambda_- e^{-i\lambda_+t}}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-}+H\frac{e^{-i\lambda_+t}-e^{-i\lambda_-t}}{\lambda_+-\lambda_-}.
$$

Comment: amazing, thank you!

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused If you like the answer, don't hesitate to upvote and accept it